# Use UISegmentedControl to build a menu like this?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a menu like this with Xcode 13 Swift 5.

Each item has different width, but the margin between two items are always the same. Additionally, the highlighting is also dynamic to text width. There will also views attached to each selected item.

Would it be possible to achieve it with UISegmentedControl?

thanks!

Comment: better to use stackview instead of segment control

Comment: I need to attach different views at the bottom to each selected items. Using StackView, i have to set conditions for when to show different view. Would there be a better solution?

Comment: well Segment control is also a stackview ... what difficulty you think you will face if you use stack instead of segment ?

Comment: for segment you also need to write conditions  when to show which view on bases of which segment selected

Comment: @user3810193 - Is there a reason you don't want to use a `UISegmentedControl`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `UIStackview`.

Look at the configuration that I have developed for you. Selected font color of the button is white and background color black otherwise font color black and bg blue. On selecting any button deselect the previous one, and boom: achieved.

[image]